# SSDP UDP Responses from ChromeCast now missing the LOCATION field

Tags: udp, google-cast

I was interacting with my ChromeCast over UDP. Last week the discovery requests were working just fine. This week the responses I'm getting back are different than they were last week. Last week things were working as described in the DIAL spec. This week I am missing the LOCATION parameter. Whereas before I would receive **LOCATION: 192.168.0.103:8008/ssdp/ssdp/device-desc.xml** (or something similar) this week I am only getting back **dp/device-desc.xml** without the LOCATION or IP address and port prefix. I tried using a different Chromecast on a different network and I got similar but not identical results. I received ssdp/device-desc.xml on one and dp/device-desc.xml on the other. Chrome seems to be able to detect the ChromeCast just fine. Did something change in the last few days?

Here is an example response that I received:

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 1
ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1

ssdp/device-desc.xml
OPT: "http://schemas.upnp.org/upnp/1/0/"; ns=01
01-NLS: 2bd4c9f6-1dd2-11b2-a755-8a9e9d005953
SERVER: Linux/3.8.13, UPnP/1.0, Portable SDK for UPnP devices/1.6.18
X-User-Agent: redsonic
ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
USN: uuid:d47145ab-0bd2-d115-9d19-d93a7cb7ae80::urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
BOOTID.UPNP.ORG: 20
CONFIGID.UPNP.ORG: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like a bug in your code doing udp receiving.

You should verify the response packet using tcpdump or other tools other than your code.